# How to pass in a method as an expression using attributes?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, lambda

I want to decorate by the attribute a test method. This attribute should know about what test is considered to be previous with regard to the attributed method. Here is an example:

```
    private void DestinationChoiceViewLoaded_AllTpmFeaturesAreEnabled_UIElementsAreSetUpProperly() {
        var vut = new DestinationChoiceViewUIWrapper();

        UIControlAssert.Clickable(vut.GetNextPageButton());
        UIControlAssert.Clickable(vut.GetPreviousPageButton());
    }

    [PreviousTestInOrder()]
    public void Run_DestinationChoiceView_Tests() {

        var vut = new DestinationChoiceViewUIWrapper();

        UIControlAssert.Clickable(vut.GetNextPageButton());
        UIControlAssert.Clickable(vut.GetPreviousPageButton());
    }
```

Somehow, I want to pass in DestinationChoiceViewLoaded_AllTpmFeaturesAreEnabled_UIElementsAreSetUpProperly to the attribute constructor.

I tried:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class PreviousTestInOrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string MethodName { get; private set; }

    public PreviousTestInOrderAttribute(Expression<Action> memberExpression) {
        MethodName = GetMemberName(memberExpression);
    }

    public static string GetMemberName(Expression<Action> memberExpression) {
        MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression) memberExpression.Body;
        return expressionBody.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

But if I do

```
[PreviousTestInOrder(() => DestinationChoiceViewLoaded_AllTpmFeaturesAreEnabled_UIElementsAreSetUpProperly)]
```

it won't compile :(

Comment: You could pass in the method name as a string and use reflection to resolve it, alternatively why not just have a TestOrder(int order) attribute taking the order the tests should be run in?

Comment: What whould you do if someone want to insert a test in the middle of the tests sequence?

Comment: Use double for the order instead of int, that way you get virtually infinite possibilities for inserting things into the sequence wherever you want without having to change the others

Comment: @mattytommo already explained why it is not possible, so not much to add there, just be aware that having tests depending on other tests is generally a bad idea.

Comment: If you run a suite of UI tests you are forced to make them ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that unfortunately, attribute parameters have to be **compile time constants**.

I guess the only alternative is to actually call that previous test before the current one is executing (first line of that test).